# Should bad questions be "bumped to the homepage by Community"?

Tags: discussion

Lately, a lot of questions were "bumped to the homepage by Community" on ux.stackexchange.com, but more than ever that questions seem to be the type of questions that should be closed. If the question is bad and not the answers, should be it still reviewed?

Comment: Funny and ironic. This question is up in the list because it was bumped by Community

Answer (score 2):

The Community User can only judge questions based off actual users' actions on the post (since it is an automated process). As far as it knows, it's not bumping bad questions.

It only [bumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/323179) "non-negatively scored, open questions [...] that have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that".

If the post warrants downvotes, then downvote. If it's off topic, you should close vote/close flag it. (This applies to all questions, actually).

If the post is closed or negatively scored then it will not be bumped, and hopefully some good on-topic question will get the bump instead.